# git push not a git repository

Tags: php, git, heroku, deployment

I'm trying to deploy an PHP application at Heroku.
I am following they're guide, that can be found here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-php 
But I got stuck in the Deploying the app step
The tutorial tells me to run git push heroku master, but I keep getting "fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git"
I've never done this before, but I tried to push other repositories and I keep getting the same message
I have no idea if the problem is with git, heroku, or if it's actually me who's doing something wrong

please help DDD:

Comment: Could be a few things, hard to say really. Are you inside the correct directory? If you run `ls -a` (Mac) is there a `.git` directory in the directory you're trying to push from?

Comment: You do have a `.git` directory in your project? What's the output from `git status` and `git remote -v` ?

Comment: First create a new branch from master branch. Then made changes. Follow Add, Commit and Push to your current repository. Then Merge current repository to Master branch

Comment: This means Git believes there is no such things as master. Are you using Git Bash? Possibly you are running commands from the wrong working directory. Make sure you are in a valid Git directory and run 'git branch' then report what the output is. Mainly, is master a response?

Comment: I actually was in the wrong directory ops :x thanks for the help :DDDDD

Answer (score -1):

I guess you are trying to push into a non-repo on the remote side.